# Safek in Pidyon haBen

Tags: halacha, safek, pidyon-haben

1. When a fatherless child with a living mother that knows he was a firstborn but does not know whether his father did the Pidyon on him.
2. When an orphan whose both parents died when he was a toddler, does not know whether he was a firstborn AND whether his father did Pidyon.

Whet's the ruling Halachah in both cases?

Comment: The former I imagine is hamotzi mechaveiro, and he doesn’t have to pay; the latter I imagine is a sefeik sefeika and definitely doesn’t have to pay.

Comment: @DonielF Isn't it Sofek DeOrayso? Hamotzi is like "it's a Kohen's problem" but isn't it the child's?

Comment: How is it different than “prove to me that I stole this object from you.”

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you mean split it into two? What's not clear?